# Tomcat and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat

Is it possible to execute .htaccess file on Tomcat?

We are trying to get phphgadmin to work and so far we can only load the first screen that display some folder links. When we click on them we get a 404 error and we suspect it might be URL rewriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run phpmyadmin on tomcat, because tomcat can't interpret php (nor it can interpret .htaccess)

What you need is Apache HTTP server, and if you need to also run Java, use [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) or mod_proxy_ajp ([comparison](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors)) - a way to let apache serve what tomcat "produces".